# How to convert elements in a matrix into binary, and expand the matrix, and can reverse the operation

Tags: python, numpy

I am implementing a homomorphic encryption algorithm， and need to convert matrix like this

```
[[3 1 3]
 [3 2 3]
 [0 1 0]]
```

which splits a vector of integers ≤q into a log(q,2) longer vector of the bits of the integers,like：

```
[[0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1]
 [0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]]
```

Then it can be calculated as a normal matrix, and the final result can be converted from the binary to integer form.

I used some algorithms in numpy that convert matrix elements to binary, but I didn't achieve what I wanted.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us what you tried and explain how the result differs from what you want. We will be happy to help you from there.

Comment: Looks like you're looking for `unpackbits`.  However, depending on your `dtype` your output won't look like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
import itertools
def expand_to_binary(my_list, q):
    my_list = [list(('{0:0' + str(q) +  'b}').format(elem)) for elem in my_list]
    my_list = [list(map(int, elem)) for elem in my_list]
    my_list = list(itertools.chain(*my_list))
    return my_list


x = [[3, 1, 3], [3, 2, 3], [0, 1, 0]]
x = [expand_to_binary(elem, 3) for elem in x]
```

`q` is the number of bits in every binary number. Although this is only the forward pass. Implementing the reverse part shouldn't be too difficult.

And this would be one way of implementing the reverse:

```
def decode_binary_to_int(my_list, q):
  my_list = [list(map(str, my_list[i: i+q])) for i in range(0, len(my_list), q)]
  my_list = [''.join(elem) for elem in my_list]
  my_list = [int(elem, 2) for elem in my_list]
  return my_list

x = [[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
x = [decode_binary_to_int[elem] for elem in x]
```

Although this code works i should say it's probably **not** the most fastest way of implementing what you want, i just tried to provide an example for what you required.

Comment: Can you show me the reverse implementation? I can only convert the entire row from binary to integer, but when there exists q, I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the reverse implementation. Although both implementations give the desired output which is what you had asked for, it might not be the fastest method if you're considered with the implementation efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `np.unpackbits`.

```
>>> matrix = np.array([3,1,3,3,2,3,0,1,0],'uint8').reshape(3,-1)
>>> matrix
array([[3, 1, 3],
       [3, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 0]], dtype=uint8)
>>> np.unpackbits(matrix.reshape(3,-1,1),2)[:,:,-3:].reshape(3,-1)
array([[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Unpackbits will unpack your ints into 8 bits, but since you only seem to be interested in the 3 least significant bits, we unpack into a new axis, and use slicing `[:,:,-3:]` to strip out the padding zeros.